# How to pass dictionary inside template literal in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-literals

How do I pass the whole dictionary inside the template literal?
Here is my code:

```js
var pvtInPlan = treatmentPlan.pavementIDs;
var pcrAfterPlan = treatmentPlan.pavementCondition;
var yearlyPlan = {};
pvtInPlan.forEach((key, i) => yearlyPlan[key] = pcrAfterPlan[i]);  // I want to pass this yearlyPlan 

var arcadeExpression = `
                                    var plan = ${yearlyPlan};   
                                    var pvtID = 100;
                                    return plan[pvtID]`; // I want to be able to return such statement.
```

Whenever I use 'var plan = ${yearlyPlan};'  line, it throws me error. It works when I use 'var plan = ${yearlyPlan[100]};' directly. But I need to pass index to this dictionary from inside of template literal.

I would be glad if someone could help me with this.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `var plan = ${JSON.stringify(yearlyPlan)};`

Comment: Why are you constructing code as a string? Don't do that and you'll avoid any problems with serialisation of your object.

Comment: I want to use this expression to filter features in ArcGIS for JS. It requires us to pass certain value for each feature from this template literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a simple `JSON.stringify` if u want to dump the entire content, for example:

```
const yearlyPlan = JSON.stringify({ key1: 'content', key2: 'content2' })
const arcadeExpression = `
                                    var plan = ${yearlyPlan};   
                                    var pvtID = 100;
                                    return plan[pvtID]`; // I want to be able to return such statement.

console.log(arcadeExpression)
>>> 
"var plan = {"key1":"content","key2":"content2"};   
var pvtID = 100;
return plan[pvtID]"
```

If you want a more customized version, then u would need to access each key-value pair to format the message.